# Is there a way to set something like adjustsfontsizetofitwidth on UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, uitabbaritem, dynamic-type-feature

Trying to get my app accessible for all users and I stumbled upon an issue when creating the items for the `TabBar` and would love to have a way of fixing it.

I got something like this in my project:

```
func setupTabBarItems(tabName: String, tabImage: UIImage?, tabSelectedImage: UIImage?) {
    let tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: tabName, image: tabImage, selectedImage: tabSelectedImage)

    tabBarItem.title = tabName
    tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: AppColor.primary], for: .selected)
    tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: AppColor.darkDeep], for: .normal)
    tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: AppFont.medium(12)], for: .normal)

    tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: -10, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    tabBarItem.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -18)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.navigationController.tabBarItem = tabBarItem
    }
}
```

and:

```
static func medium(_ fontSize: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
    let font = UIFont(name: AppFont.someRandomTextFont, size: fontSize)!
    let fontMetrics = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body)
    return fontMetrics.scaledFont(for: font)
}
```

When increasing the `dynamic text type`, the `title` gets out of the actual item.
For example, when doing this for a `UILabel` I just check the "`Automatically Adjust Font`" option and update "`Minimum Font Scale`" to 0.25.

Is there any way to do something like this in the code describing the `TabBarItem` programmatically?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, I know. But I just stumbled over Large Content Viewer, introduced in iOS 13.

If user has set the device's font (or the app-specific font) to something in the accessibility font range, you get Large Content Viewer for free. Tap and hold the tab bar item to see a large view of the tab bar item, with enlarged image and text.

https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/wwdc/2019/261/ has a nice summary. The original WWDC video was [WWDC 2019, session 261](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/261/). Note that you'll want the image asset to be a vector format if possible.

There's also a protocol, `UILargeContentViewerItem`, that your custom API can adopt.

This seems to be Apple's preferred way of making tab bar items, status bars, nav bars, standard UIKit controls, and images accessible to low-vision users who aren't using an assistive device.

Comment: Many other summaries of WWDC videos are also available ⟹ https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/wwdc/nota11y/ 

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to do something like this in the code describing the TabBarItem programmatically?

**No**, the `UITabBarItem` is definitely **not made for this kind of purpose**.
You can change some attributes using the appearance proxy for instance but there's no such things provided by Apple to handle your situation.

> Trying to get my app accessible for all users...

I understand you're willing to implement a11y and Apple introduced an interesting feature dealing with `UITabBarItem`: the [Large Content Viewer](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/wwdc/2019/261/).
The `UITabBarItem` inherits from `UIBarItem` that exposes some `largeContent...` properties which highlights this feature I do recommend.

I'm not sure your concept may provide more a11y to your app because the [tab bar items aren't made for that in my view](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/261/?time=114).
Anyway, I always try to avoid text in my tab bars: **explicit SF Symbols** may be another appropriate solution.

**IF** you really want to follow your idea, you could be informed of the text sizes setting *(`traitCollectionDidChange`)* and adapt your font size accordingly using the 'mmmatey' method for instance (measurements ) ⟹ why not but I really don't recommend this way of conception.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it something like this

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    tabBar.subviews.forEach { barButton in
        barButton.subviews.forEach { subview in
            if let label = subview as? UILabel {
                label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`UITabBarItem` doesn't contain label - so that you will be able to set minimum scale directly.

Suggestion would be to go with custom views instead of UITabBarItems.

Or if you prefer to continue with `UITabBarItem`, I suggest that you do measuring by yourself. Measure the size of the text/font you want and if it's too big, make the font size small enough that it will fit.